# Trying to execute a voicenote function in my app, but this code keeps crashing it

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app in android studio, where this code is necessary to reset the voicenote after it plays, but it keeps crashing my app and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated as I'm still rather new to Java.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            isPlaying = false;
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
            play.setText("Play");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you get any error log?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.kruline.audiorecorder, PID: 2241
    java.lang.IllegalStateException

Comment: at android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(Native Method)
            at com.kruline.audiorecorder.MainActivity$4.run(MainActivity.java:94)

Comment: Along with a bit more